# How can I authenticate PeerJS connections to the PeerServer?

Tags: authentication, webrtc, peerjs

I am currently running my own PeerServer while I develop an application. I am wondering how I can authenticate each individual ID so that when someone connects, then have to have the right API key (unique to their name).

Could I set up a service where, when they register, a new key is generated and peerjs will recognize it?

Comment: You can do this, and perhaps you can integrate peerjs into your security scheme so that it has access, or it calls some kind of api to validate that the user has access

Comment: What would be a secure way to generate API keys on first connection?

Comment: There is an node module, uuid, which will generate random ids for you https://github.com/kelektiv/node-uuid

Comment: did you get an answer to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can send a token in the options, for example a JWT with the userId encoded:

```js
const myPeer = new Peer(userId, {
    host: '/',
    token: userJwt
})
```

Receive it when the user connects and validate it. If the ids don't match, close the socket:

```js
peerServer.on('connection', client => { 
    const decodedToken = decodeToken(client.token)
    if (!decodedToken || decodedToken.userId != client.id)
        client.socket.close()
})
```

Comment: Thanks! I created an issue on peerjs github repository
https://github.com/peers/peerjs/issues/897